# This interval question is too hard for me, can anyone explain fully to me?

Tags: integration

Let $f$ be the function defined by

$f(x)=\left\{\begin{matrix}2x-x^2,  x\leqslant 1\\x^2 + kx+p,  x> 1\end{matrix}\right.$

(1). For what value of $k$ and $p$ will $f$ be continuous and differentiable at $x=1?$

(2). For what value of $k$ and $p$ found in (1), on what inteval and intervals is $f$ increasing?

(3). Determine the global maximum and minimum values in the interval $\left [ -2,2 \right ]$

Comment: Are you saying you don't know how to find when a function is increasing, and you don't know how to find global maxima and minima of a function? Or is it really just (1) that you don't know how to solve? Or do you know how to solve (1) but not the others? What makes (1) difficult for you? You really should ask about what specifically you're having problems with, rather than just posting your homework assignments.

Comment: I dont really understand the continuous thing thus I can't slove the whole question.

Answer (score 1):

Exercise: is the function

$$f(x)=\left\{\begin{matrix}2x-x^2,  x\leqslant 1\\x^2 + 3x+7,  x> 1\end{matrix}\right.$$

continuous and differentiable at $1$?

Solving (1) is pretty much exactly the same work as solving this problem.

Comment: Do I differeniate the function above first? 2-2x and 2x+3?